# Screen displays only black, but can tell it's connected and can display "Not Connected" message when it isn't

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have an Acer monitor I'm connecting via DVI. It worked until recently but suddenly stopped. Now, when it's connected and on, it turns off-- no backlight, no nothing. But when I disconnect it, it shows a "no signal" message.

Comment: try press Window + P ..

Comment: tried that, but nope

Comment: What is showing on the screen? Is it the same as in your question.. : "But when I disconnect it, it shows a.. "

Comment: Oops, looks like that sentence got cut off somehow. I'll edit the OP.

Anyway, when I press Win+P with the monitor connected, the monitor still shows nothing-- No message, no backlight.

Comment: 1. When you press the [ Win+P ],  you should hold the Win and release the P. There should be an option sticking out (for multiple monitors). | 2. Tried [ r-click @ Desktop > Display setting > detect ] ? Should see it there too. | 3. (just as extra info) "no backlight, no nothing. But when I disconnect it, it shows a "no signal" message." means.. the monitor is successfully connected, it was the graphic card that 'commands' the monitor to show 'nothing'. imho, you have no hardware/connection failure, just settle the configurations/updateDriver should do.